# Suggestions For Adding Values To Sub-Strings With Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, substring

I am looking for suggestions as to how to get python to convert an empty space within a sub-string to a dash (-).

In the below dataframe column **A** has the raw data and need to add a dash to the sub-strings that have a space in them to get column **B**

Any suggestions how to overcome this?

[image]

Comment: `df.A.str.replace(' ','-')` is what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about **[replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)**:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': ['ADMCAP B', 'ATHENA', 'ATLA DKK', 'BNORDIK CSE']})
>>> df
             A
0     ADMCAP B
1       ATHENA
2     ATLA DKK
3  BNORDIK CSE
>>> df['B'] = df['A'].replace(' ', '-', regex=True)
>>> df
             A            B
0     ADMCAP B     ADMCAP-B
1       ATHENA       ATHENA
2     ATLA DKK     ATLA-DKK
3  BNORDIK CSE  BNORDIK-CSE
```

Or you could use: `df['B'] = df['A'].str.replace(' ', '-')`